# How to use the removeClass() to remove class from all similar Items

Tags: jquery, html, plugins

Here is my html:

```
<dl>
<dt>Options 1</dt>
<dd>Link 1</dd>
<dd>Link 2</dd>
<dd>Link 3</dd>
<dt>Option 2</dt>
<dd>Link 4</dd>
<dd>Link 5</dd>
<dd>Link 6</dd>
</dl>
```

I have created a plugin for the effect that I desire with this menu. here is my plugin:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.Pointer = function() {
        var txt, y;
        txt = $(this);
        txt.on("click", function(event){
            y=event.pageY;
            y = y - 15;

            //animate pointer
            $('#pointer').animate({ 'top' : y + 'px'});
            //adding hover class to selected links
            txt.addClass("select_menu");
        });
    };
})( jQuery );

$("dd").each(function(){
    $(this).Pointer();
});
```

Quick explanation of the plugin effect. I have a div with an arrow that points to the link that you click on. Every time you click, the arrow slides to the new link that was clicked on(This slider is working fine). Also I have the clicked link change class. Here is my first issue. When you click on link 1 the class is being applied. What I want to do is click on Link 2 and the previous class that was applied to Link 1, I want cleared and the class applied on the new clicked link. I am having trouble removing the class from the previous clicked link. Can someone help me with this?

I hope that the explanation was clear enough.

Comment: The collapsing issue belongs in a separate question, don't ask people to walk you through your whole project. Also semantically this is a bad use of `<dl>`. Also please reduce and format your code samples - this one has a bunch of tangential not really relevant stuff. (Like the `.animate()` call.)

Comment: `this.addClass('select_menu').closest('dl').find('dd').not(this).removeClass('select_menu');`

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand from your question, you can try something like this for removing and adding the classes:

```
$(".arrow").click(function(){
    $(".myClass").removeClass("myClass");
    $(this).addClass("myClass");
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Have the plugin act on a whole group of items, then just clear the class from all of them before reapplying it. I.e. structure it something like:

```
$.fn.Pointer = function() {
  var $group = this;
  $group.on('click.Pointer', function() {
    var $link = $(this);

    $group.removeClass('select_menu')
    $link.addClass('select_menu')
  });
};

$('dd').Pointer();
```

Whatever group of elements you call `.Pointer()` in will only ever have the `.select_menu` class applied to one element out of them.

Example on Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/hidFq

Comment: Shouldn't the **this** be $(this)?

Comment: @Bryan Obviously not since the code works. The context of plugin functions is the entire selector, you're thinking of `.each()`